# Why i am not getting exact output ? My php code below

Tags: php, json

```
$a="https://www.flameyt.xyz/test/channelsfolder/DYNO/data.json";

$b=file_get_contents($a);

$json=json_decode($b,true);

$channellink=$json['1']['channellink'];

$totalamount=$json['1']['totalamount'];

$totalmembers=$json['1']['totalmembers'];

$amountpereach=$json['1']['amountpereach'];

$comments=$json['1']['comments'];

$subid=$_json['1']['subid'];

$mid=$_json['1']['mid'];

$mkey=$_json['1']['mkey'];

echo "$subid";
```

Comment: What is `$_json`?, and what exact output?

Answer (score 2):

Change `$_json` to `$json`

Try this:

```
<?php 

    $a = "https://www.flameyt.xyz/test/channelsfolder/DYNO/data.json";

    $b = file_get_contents($a);

    $json = json_decode($b,true);

    $channellink = $json['1']['channellink'];

    $totalamount = $json['1']['totalamount'];

    $totalmembers = $json['1']['totalmembers'];

    $amountpereach = $json['1']['amountpereach'];

    $comments = $json['1']['comments'];

    $subid = $json['1']['subid'];

    $mid = $json['1']['mid'];
    
    $mkey = $json['1']['mkey'];

    echo $subid;

?>
```